# What is the best way to model RBAC in MongoDB: To Embed or To Link?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database-schema, data-modeling, rbac

As the question suggests should I link or Embed?
Number of users in one of the role could scale to tens of thousands. How should it be modelled?
Problem is number of DataBase queries that are to be done :

1. when updating permission of role.
2. when checking each request what is the role and what are its permissions.
3. Getting role and Permission in profile.